# Progressive array combinations in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, cartesian-product

I have multiple arrays, lets say 4 for example:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c" ]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c = ["xx", "yy"]
d = ["abc"]
```

I'd like to "progressively" do product of arrays in an iterative fashion, something like this

```
a.product(b)
a.product(b, c)
a.product(b, c, d)
```

I want to be able to do in a scalable fashion where the array count varies and get array product upto `arr0.product(arr1, arr2, arr3.......arrn)`.Could someone please help figure out how to do this in Ruby.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = ["a", "b", "c" ]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c = ["xx", "yy"]
d = ["abc"]

ars = [b,c,d]
p ars.each_index.flat_map{|i| a.product(*ars[0..i])}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could abstract it like this:

```
def prog_product(arrs)
  x, *xs = arrs
  (1..xs.count).map(&xs.method(:take)).map do |args|
    x.product(*args)
  end
end
```

This will return an array of the progressive products, such as:

```
[a1.product(a2), ..., a1.product(a2, ..., an)]
```

In your case, `prog_products(a, b, c, d)` would return `[a.product(b), a.product(b, c), a.product(b, c, d)]`. If for some reason you wanted to merge all the products into one big array, you may call `.flatten(1)` on the result.